# GTK/QT File Chooser: automatically search in subfolders

Tags: linux, qt, gtk3

is there a way to let these two file choosers automatically look in subfolders?

Up until a few months ago, I could be in the gtk3 file chooser in /home/me and type 'stock' and it would suggest /home/me/some/deep/folder/stock.txt

Unfortunately this doesn't happen anymore, and I just noticed how much I miss it.
Is there a way to make it happen in the GTK3 file chooser, and is there something similar in the Qt equivalent?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your *current* gtk3 version? On Debian-based systems, `dpkg -l libgtk2.0-0 libgtk-3-0` would provide that information. I don't know of a convenient command to dig out the `qt` version. On Kubuntu 18.04, `kf5-config --version` gives me the current `qt` version.

Comment: gtk3: 3.24.16;
qt: 5.14.2.
(on Arch Linux: `pacman -Qi gtk3 qt5-base | grep ^Ver` )